# Windows phone 8.1 Accelerometer and updating UI

Tags: c#, windows-phone, accelerometer, windows-phone-8.1, uiaccelerometer

I having problems finding documentation or examples regarding the proper way to use the Accelerometer as well as updating a textbox using Dispatcher. Seems like it should be easy, but all the examples are 8.0 which apparently used using **Microsoft.Devices.Sensors;**

Apparently you are supposed to use using Windows.Devices.Sensors; which you would think are the same, but things like Start() and Stop methods no longer exist. I was trying to use a Microsoft AccelerometerHelper class from Microsoft [here](http://www.getcodesamples.com/src/AF7244DF/235A248A)

Also the older Dispatcher is now CoreDispatcher based on [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.dependencyobject.dispatcher)?

Also was trying to use this library, but it also uses the old namespace: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Shake-Gesture-Library-04c82d5f

Can anyone either provide an example or direct me to some information on how in 8.1, you would register the Accelerometer events and update the UI textbox with something like the x-axis?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you developing a Silverlight or WinRT app?

Comment: @igrali - I am building a phone 8.1 app that may end up a universal app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Silverlight 8.1 for this particular app per Microsoft. They are "looking" into why the phone API is the only one without a shake event.

Answer (score 3):

Try this code for **Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight** application. It uses `Accelerometer` class from `Microsoft.Devices.Sensors`

```
// initialize
Accelerometer accelerometer = new Accelerometer();
accelerometer.CurrentValueChanged += accelerometer_CurrentValueChanged;
accelerometer.Start();

void accelerometer_CurrentValueChanged(object sender, SensorReadingEventArgs<AccelerometerReading> e)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        XAxisText.Text = e.SensorReading.Acceleration.X.ToString();
    });
}
```

For **Windows Phone Universal application** use next code:

```
Accelerometer accelerometer = Accelerometer.GetDefault();
accelerometer.ReadingChanged += accelerometer_ReadingChanged; 

async void accelerometer_ReadingChanged(Accelerometer sender, AccelerometerReadingChangedEventArgs args)
{
    await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        XAxisText.Text = args.Reading.AccelerationX.ToString();
    });            
}
```

Comment: Apparently I can't access that namespace from Windows 8.1 phone templates? When I go to Add References, it does not show up as an option? Is that some extension or something? I have using Windows.Devices.Sensors; available  to me that's it. Also 8.0 seems to have still had the namespace you provide above.

Comment: @ku6oper. Thank you I will try this and if it works, maybe I can adapt shake gesture library to use this technique. Are you familiar with that library at all? I thought detecting a shake would be easy, but apparently it is not so easy

Comment: Please look at `Shaken` event of `Accelerometer` class. Maybe it's what you want

Comment: @ku6oper: From MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.sensors.accelerometer.shaken.aspx 
Windows Phone 8:  The accelerometer sensor does not raise the Shaken event on the Windows Phone 8 platform. If you add an event handler for the Shaken event in your Windows Phone 8 app, no error is raised, but the code in the event handler won’t run.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem and could't figure out how to make Shake event work.
Then I found this examples on Microsoft site http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Windows-Phone-81-samples-08631ca7
In the Accelerometer solution I found very nice description "Windows Phone does not have an accelerometer shake event@. So it seems like we're have to write our own implementation of Shake Event)

Comment: Yes.. I tried the same one... funny how it says phone supported.. not so much. I spoke to a guy at Microsoft and he said to use Silverlight 8.1... for this App it will be ok to go with. They are looking into it though since the phone is the only one without a Shake event.